# Daily Firebase HTTP Request to trigger FCM Notification

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have FCM up and running in my app and I can send notifications through the Firebase console to all users or a specific user based on the fcmToken stored in a user's profile.

My app allows users to submit daily updates, answers to a set of questions about their health. Whenever a user does this I update the child path /userId/lastDailyUpdate with a date in form yyyyMMdd (ie. 20170805) as an Integer. I do this so that I can hide the questions and submit views if a user has already submitted their input for that specific day.

What I would like to do now, is to use Firebase Cloud Functions in combination with a daily cron job at 8pm to check if a user has submitted their answers. In short, if current date (yyyyMMdd as Int) is larger than date Int stored in /userId/lastDailyUpdate send a notification.

I can send notifications using Cloud Functions, but cannot find a way to loop through all users in my database and checking their lastDailyUpdate values. My code so far:

```
    let functions = require('firebase-functions');
    let admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

    exports.sendDailyReminder = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Daily Reminder Function");

    let userId = "P3fPW62PaxX45Ccvo4OiyOk6fJC2"

    // See the "Defining the message payload" section below for details
    // on how to define a message payload.
    var payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Had a healthy day?',
            body: 'Submit you stats before you go to sleep.',
            badge: '1',
            sound: 'default'
        }
    };
    return admin.database().ref('/users/P3fPW62PaxX45Ccvo4OiyOk6fJC2/fcmToken').once('value').then(allToken => {
        if (allToken.val()) {
            const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(response => {
            });
        }
    });
    });
```

The above code works, but as you can imagine I want to send to more than 1 user :)

The path to lastDailyUpdate value (for user 'P3fPW62PaxX45Ccvo4OiyOk6fJC2' in this example) is:

```
    '/users/P3fPW62PaxX45Ccvo4OiyOk6fJC2/lastDailyUpdate'
```

I have only been programming for a short while, I know a good amount of JS, but these functions have got me puzzled. Is there anyone who can help me in the right direction?

I am thinking of a HTTP request to trigger a for loop that checks the lastDailyInput value and if smaller than current date trigger then sending of a notification.

Any help with code or tips (possibly on a crash course for Express/Node.js) would be very much appreciated.

Comment: For running scheduled jobs with Cloud Functions, see [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA). For additional help with the actual code: don't describe your code and data structure, but share the [actual code and JSON (as text, no screenshots please) that reproduce where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To get the JSON, click the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: For the cron job, I recommend https://cron-job.org - it's even in one of the great Firebase YouTube videos.

Comment: thanks @Frank for the google-cloud-functions tag, I was looking for something similar.

Comment: @MatthewNiederberger Please edit your question to include the requested information. There's a small edit link under it.

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for the tip. I have added a JSON snippet from my database. Unfortunately I have no code example from the Firebase Function since I could not find a template or example to get me started. apologies for the beginner's mistakes here on Stack Overflow concerning my posts.